# replacing the particular line in bash

Tags: command-line, sed, awk

I wanted to change 800 line in one file say test.txt
if i use the below command it works

```
sed -i '800s/old_pattern/new_pattern/' $filepath
```

Is there a way to pass the line number through variable like below

```
sed -i '"$linenum"s/old_pattern/new_pattern/' $filepath
```

I tried the above but not working please help

Answer (score 0):

`$linenum` won't get expanded if it's inside the single quotes - you just need to move it outside:

```
sed -i "$linenum"'s/old_pattern/new_pattern/' "$filepath"
```